# How can I replace fields filled out by local state and set them with a Redux-Form instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form

I have a form which comes to the UI in a modal. It is a form which is already filled out since it is to edit the information that is already there.

So I am fetching the information on that form on a `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { passengerInfo } = this.props;

    if (passengerInfo) {
      this.setState({
        id: passengerInfo.id,
        address: passengerInfo.address,
      });
    }
  }
```

Then I set that info on the fields:

```
   const addressField = () => (
      <AddEditFormInputs
        inputName="address"
        onChangeText={address => this.setState({ address })}
        textStateValue={address}
      />
    );
    ...
    <Field name="address" component={addressField} />
```

Above, `textStateValue` is the value of the input, so, if `address` input has information, it will print it when the form comes to the UI, and the same for the other fields.

The problem I am having is that if I close and open again that modal, then the field gets restored. I guess it is because I am setting the state on a `componentDidMount`.

So, what can I do to keep the state of the form using a Redux-Form?

As you see I am already using Redux-Form here -> `<Field name="address" component={addressField} />` but I need some

[I recorded a video for you to have an idea of how the modal opens with the form already filled out](https://monosnap.com/file/H2QSNj7jabblEWFRO0Z9peJGTjdr7i)

**EDIT**

Something I forgot to post is that I also can set this fields information with data coming from a redux-store. Like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      passengerInfo,
    } = this.props;

    if (passengerInfo) {
      editPassengerDataActionActionHandler({
        id: passengerInfo.id,
        address: passengerInfo.address,
      });
  }
```

With that above I am trying to change the information as well and it will get restored to the original values if I don't submit the form.